# How to insert multiple composite objects into an array field

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, prisma

I have already asked this question on the prisma forum. Here's a link to that discussion:

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18332

As stated, I am searching for a way to do this in a programmatic manner. So here is my code snippet

```
        const newDevice = await this.prismaService.deviceModel.create({
            data: {
                modelNumber: device.modelNumber,
                parts: {
                    set: device.parts
                }
            }
        })
```

where device.parts is an array consisting of objects with {partNumber: string, quantity: number, partName: string} structures.

The code snippet above returns an interesting error. It returns:

```
         +     partNumber: String,
         +     quantity: Int,
         +     partName: String
             }
           }
         })

Unknown arg `set` in data.parts.set for type DevicePartsCreateInput. Did you mean `select`?
Argument partNumber for data.parts.partNumber is missing.
Argument quantity for data.parts.quantity is missing.
Argument partName for data.parts.partName is missing.

Note: Lines with + are required
```

However, when I manually insert an object, it will successfully perform the insert. Any ideas?

I have tried:

- generating a new prisma "npx prisma generate"
- setting set: device.parts.map(s => ({partNumber: s.partNumber, quantity: s.quantity, partName: s.partName}))
- using CreateMany instead of set

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for your qestion:

```
await this.prismaService.deviceMode.create({
  data: {
    modelNumber: device.modelNumber,
    parts: {
      createMany: {
        data: device.parts,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.